# nginx - Friendly URL's in directory

Tags: php, linux, nginx, friendly-url

I move my Friendly URL's from Apache to nginx and I have a problem. I want to Friendly URL's only works within the subdirectory **sgforum**.

In PHP, I receive the addresses as: ***127.0.0.1/sgforum/index***, ***127.0.0.1/sgforum/member*** etc.

When I go on *127.0.0.1/sgforum/* - it works, but when I give **member** (***127.0.0.1/sgforum/member***), or **index**, it downloads a file to my computer, instead of opening with php.

This is my ***/etc/nginx/sites-available/default*** file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/ariel/workspace;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # FRIENDLY URLS
    location /sgforum/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/sgforum/(.*)$ /sgforum/index.php break;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it, and finally works as it should.

```
# FRIENDLY URLS
location /sgforum/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sgforum/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Had a similar issue and this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you have to set location for member folder

Comment: member - is not a directory, it is an argument that answer in the PHP $ _SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and selects a specific action.

Comment: when you downloaded a file it means you have to adjust php-fpm settings

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev, could you post both your answers as one, thorough one?

Answer (score -1):

try change

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Now I have 404 for any phrase entered, but still saves the correct URLs as sgforum/member to file member.